# Specify Maven plugin repository from the commandline

Tags: maven

I want to use maven's dependency:get to download a package. I need to configure both a remote repository and a plugin repository. If I configure it in settings.xml it works:

(Example settings.xml from https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      ...
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>codehausSnapshots</id>
          <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <url>http://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        ...
      </pluginRepositories>
      ...
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ...
</settings>
```

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=<artifact>
```

However I would like to be able to do this without configuring the settings.xml file. I know dependency:get lets you specify a -DremoteRepositories argument. There there any way to specify the plugin repository? In my particular case both repositories are actually the same location however if I only provide -DremoteRepositories maven fails to download the plugins.

Comment: Codehaus repos are dead very long...

Comment: @khmarbaise yes you are correct. As stated in the problem I'm only using an example setting.xml from the maven documentation. My actual configuration is for a private repository mirror that I cannot share in a SO post.